# hide url in inspect code to protect from download

Tags: laravel

Im using futurepress/epubjs-reader to display user's bought books on my site . Im using laravel and books in public folder. Here code in view :

```
<script>
    "use strict";

    document.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (document.readyState == "complete") {

        window.reader = ePubReader("{{ url($e_book->getSource())}}", {
           restore: true
         });

      }
    };

</script>
```

where I accept path to book from controller in inspect code look like this

```
window.reader = ePubReader("http://site.kz/books/booktitle.epub", {
```

So if someone inspects code can find url to book and download it and any other books because books in public folder. I dont want it . I dont want full protect of books from download because in this case I need to move books to another folder than public. I just want not to show path in code . Any idea how to do it?

Im dont want to move books because I need them as url then js by own read this ebook . If I move books to private folder then get them with controller then as I know I can just download them . But I need path to give it to js .

Comment: What if you create a route to the books, and include for example a token that can only be used once with the URL. You can definitely show the book's url - not directly from the public folder, but via that route and then you simply invalidate the token with the url after every call on that url? This means having the url doesn't even do anything after the ePubReader has shown it once.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin I didnt get it . Can you please explain .  I have folder public/books . And when I go to website.com/books/booktitle.epub it downloads

Answer (score 2):

You should not place protected files in the `public/` folder, but create a folder in `storage/`. Then you can create a web route yourself on which you check if the user has access to this file and download the file if so.

Comment: In my case nobody have access to download books . If I keep books in storage folder . then controller sends to view source . In view script trying to get website.com/storage/booktitle.epub   . It will fail because it looks for storage folder in public

Comment: Just use [file responses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#file-downloads) with files in your storage folder.

Comment: script get only path . Not book . After that I dont know how it work . Nothing about it in github